# Laravel 5.2 auth User passing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel, Please bear with me How would I pass the current logged on user from the controller to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass it to the view.

Using the `Auth` facade, or `auth()` helper you have access to the current user:

```
// Use the Auth facade
{{ Auth::user()->email }}

// Or use the Auth helper:
{{ auth()->user()->email }}
```

Comment: Uhmm, one more thing. how would I do it in a form hidden like this, there seems to be an error {{ Form::hidden('user_id',  {{ auth()->user()->id }}) }}

Comment: @RHAMAB
The problem is the same of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283247/laravel-nested-blade-echos/39283437#39283437

You are trying to put blade tags inside blade tags.
Once you opened blade tags, you are writing PHP, not blade anymore.

So you should do:

`{{ Form::hidden('user_id', auth()->user()->id) }}`
Note the use of just a pair of `{{ ... }}`